# Alterar a cor do link do fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, css

Colegas.

Estou usando o Fullcalendar para uma aplicação de um cliente, porém deparei-me com um desafio. Na imagem abaixo (onde está marcado com um círculo amarelo), quando se tem mais de um evento no dia, aparece um link **mais +2**, onde ao clicar aparece os eventos daquele dia, porém preciso colocar o link em branco e não estou conseguindo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei usar o código abaixo diretamente na página e no arquivo fullcalendar.css, porém só o a:hover funcionou:

```
a:link{
    text-decoration: underline; 
    color: #FFF;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none
    }
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline; 
    color: #FFF;
    }
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: usa o inspetor de elementos, descobre quais são as classes dos links, ou dos elementos pais, e então passe sua stylesheet para a ultima a ser requisitada (para que seu estilo seja processado por cima de outros estilos passados por bibliotecas), ex: `.calendar-day a{color:red;}`

Comment: a classe usada por eles é `a.fc-more` no próprio link, acabei de verificar

Comment: Perfeito Murilo. Funcionou!! Obrigado!

Comment: responde a própria pergunta com o método usado, pra evitar fechamento por inatividade :)

Answer (score 1):

Conforme ajuda do Murilo Gambôa, consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
a.fc-more {
    margin: 1px 3px;
    font-size: .85em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
```